# Problem with copying JSON file as one row in into a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, file, copy

I have a simple JSON document "example_1.JSON:

```
{
"fruit": "Apple",
"size": "Large",
"color": "Red"
}
```

I created a temp table "temp_json" to copy the file into it:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_json (mydata text);
```

I copied the JSON file using the following statement:

```
COPY temp_json from 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\example_1.JSON';
```

It is ok with the copy part. When I insert the values from the temp table into my database table "jsontable", the insertion happens with no errors, but it inserts the JSON values in several rows inside my database table!!!
My database table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.jsontable (
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('jsontable_id_seq'::regclass),
  jsondata jsonb,
  CONSTRAINT jsontable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The insert statement from the temp table to the jsontable:

```
INSERT INTO jsontable(jsondata) SELECT to_jsonb(mydata::text) FROM temp_json;
```

But when I select rows from jsontable, I don't get the JSON values in a single row!

```
SELECT * FROM jsontable;
```

[image]

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Your data should be on a single line, with literal newlines replaced by the newline character: `{\n"fruit": "Apple",\n"size": "Large",\n"color": "Red"\n}`. You will then be able to import it.

Comment: I tried it but it gave me a different result, it didn't allow me to copy the file in the temp table as one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Control the data from the source file, i.e. pre-format the contents of the file to have them on a single line before copying.

Another option might be to concatenate the lines using `string_agg`. To maintain the order, I would suggest you to have a default identity column in your temp table.

```
create sequence seq_temp_json;

CREATE temp TABLE temp_json 
  ( 
     id     INT DEFAULT NEXTVAL('seq_temp_json'::regclass), 
     mydata TEXT 
  );
```

Now, load the temp table and check the order, json order should be in the ascending order of id.

```
  COPY temp_json(mydata) from 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\example_1.JSON';

knayak=# select * from temp_json;
 id |      mydata
----+-------------------
  1 | {
  2 | "fruit": "Apple",
  3 | "size": "Large",
  4 | "color": "Red"
  5 | }
(5 rows)
```

Load the JSON into main table

```
INSERT INTO jsontable ( jsondata ) 
SELECT   string_agg( mydata ,e'\n' ORDER BY id)::jsonb 
FROM     temp_json;
```

The column now contains the complete JSONB.

```
knayak=# select * from jsontable;
 id |                      jsondata
----+-----------------------------------------------------
  6 | {"size": "Large", "color": "Red", "fruit": "Apple"}
(1 row)
```